# Require users to install Facebook app when clicking on a frictionless sharing link

Tags: facebook

I've recently created a Facebook App that uses frictionless sharing.  I was expecting that when people see activity in their feed (for example, when a friend sees that you've read an article), that users that click on it would be prompted to install the app.  This is similar to what happens with Yahoo's and The Independent's Facebook apps.

However, with our Facebook application, there is no such prompting.  When a user sees the activity in their feed, the link goes directly to the webpage, with no prompt to install the app themselves.

Does anyone know how to get the same frictionless sharing behavior as Yahoo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frictionless sharing and the new auth dialog are separate. To mirror Yahoo's functionality you'll want to turn on authenticated referrals, which is an advanced setting for your application. The authenticated referral mechanism will require the user to install your application before Facebook serves your canvas page to them, in order to bypass the redirect chain that happens when you manually prompt for permissions from within your application.

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/authentication/#referrals for more details.